# Charge one customer for all in app purchases with code

Tags: java, android, billing

Its not clear to me how to charge one customer for app downloads, googling didn't help, the only thing I can think of is in app billing, but my understanding is that it would be on a user by user basis.

Do people do this and how? What would be the easiest way?

Another idea I had would be one app is downloaded and this app would make in app purchases for 'keys', after which an app is downloaded and the key sent, but each key should only be used once, so a server back end to keep track seems necessary.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/monetizing.html

Comment: What are you asking?  Are you trying to get your app into the Google Play Store and charge from there?  Do you have add-ons or something inside your app that you want to charge for?  Why didn't the documentation help you?

Comment: Basically a company contacted me to make an app, I can put it on the market, but they'll pay for it when their users download it. I'm trying to figure out how to allow the users to download free but only charge the business